# What is the difference between a chord and a triad on a piano -( or any instrument capable of playing multiple notes simultaneously)?

Tags: theory, piano, chords

I do not understand the difference between a chord and a triad. Are they the same thing or do they have differences? (i.e. Cmaj. chord v.s. Cmaj. triad)

Comment: I think we can cut "on a piano" from this, because it's the same idea no matter what instruments we're making the notes on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic accepted definition of a chord is minimum three separate notes.Some would be happy saying two. Thus a triad is a chord. However, chords can have more than three separate (named) notes. So, triads are chords, but chords may not be triads.

The most used triads are 1,3 and 5. Translating in key C to C, E, and G. There are four different types of triads - *major, minor, diminished and augmented*. Majors have (consecutive) intervals of M3 and m3. Minors have m3 and M3. Diminisheds have m3 and m3, while augmenteds have M3 and M3.

Since triads have three and only three notes played, those can be *voiced* close or open. Close has all three notes as near as possible to each other, giving for example, C E G, or E G C, or G C E as the options - root, 1st and 2nd inversions, in that order.

Open triads use the same notes (here in key C) but they could be anywhere on the instrument (obviously an instrument which can play all simultaneously), and those inversions are dictated by the lowest note.

It stands to reason that any or all of those three notes could be played in multiple octaves, and often are. Then, they still constitute only C major, but then it's played as a *chord* - triads having only three notes.

Comment: The definition of a chord is not three notes.

Comment: As if there was "_the_" definition.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - to whom is your comment directed?

Comment: When I was getting my music theory B.A., in my introductory tonal harmony course, someone asked what the difference was between a chord and an interval, and the professor said that an interval has two notes and a chord has three or more, more-or-less. I don't think there is a "true definition set in stone" as with many things in music theory, but I think Tim's definition is perfectly reasonable as far as this question goes. If you don't need to distinguish between intervals and chords, defining a chord as two or more notes seems fine to me too. You're just picking your tools.

Comment: @ZoëSparks - an interval can only have two notes - it's the 'space' between them. That's categoric. Chord definition is rather more vague. Having only two notes (or pitch classes) makes it very difficult - I'd say impossible - to give a specific name to the combination, as far as saying what 'chord' it might be. The special term for two notes is a dyad. When commenting, it helps to use '@name' to direct the comment towards another, or their own comment.

Comment: This is totally esoteric hair-splitting, but I took @MichaelCurtis 's comment to mean "Well, 'chord' implies functional relationship between those notes." Like, when is it a chord and when is it just a pitch cluster.

Comment: Tim: Yes I know, re intervals/chords/etc., my comment was in response to Michael Curtis—sorry for any confusion!

@AndyBonner Unless we're getting into really esoteric territory where concepts like "chord" have little sway, I guess my intuition is that you can find some way to harmonically categorize just about any set of vertical pitches given the context. There's always some kind of meaningful relationship between them, unless the composer was making moves entirely at random (and even then it's kind of a philosophical question). Maybe not a traditional tonal relationship, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 9):

*Chord* is the broad category and *triad* is a specific kind of chord.

The simultaneous sounding of multiple tones makes chords. Here is a quote from Elie Siegmeister's *Harmony and Melody*...

> Harmony had its roots in the *chord* - a group of tones sounded simultaneously.

Even more importantly chords are *conceptual*, you need to analyze music to determine *which tones* combine to make chords. In many cases it can be ambiguous which tones constitute the tones of a chord.

*Triads* are chords of three tones, a third and a fifth above a root tone. Usually the implication is the tones are stacked up thirds, but to be technically clear, such chords built of thirds are called *tertian* chords.

Going back to Rameau and the concept of the *perfect chord* common practice harmony is triadic. Many harmony texts define a chord as three tones which makes sense, because triadic harmony is the topic of those texts. Other texts, like Siegmeister's define *chord* as simultaneous sounding of any number of tones. There really isn't a conflict between those differing definitions. It's just a matter of whether the focus is on triadic harmony or the broad sense of harmony as the vertical combination of tones.

In your example...

> i.e. Cmaj. chord v.s. Cmaj. triad

The general understanding would be those terms are synonymous. But, as "chord" is a broad concept, it should be understood that a "C major chord" could refer to an incomplete chord of, for example, the root and third. "C major triad" is more specific and you would expect it means all three chord tones are actually present.

These terms apply regardless of instrumentation. They would be used the same for piano, guitar, chorus, etc. etc.

Comment: If 'C major chord' refers to an incomplete chord, then it's Cmajor *incomplete chord*, not a chord. A dyad.

Comment: This is just basic category stuff. Incomplete chord is a subset of chord. And dyad just means a two tone chord.

Comment: Following Piston, if "_the combination of two or more intervals makes a chord,_" then the combination of three or more notes makes a chord, no?

Comment: @exnihilo, I see what you mean. two _intervals_, not two _pitches_. I replaced that quotation with another to clarify my point, and added a general comment about triadic harmony.

Comment: My problem is naming two note chords. C+E = C major (no 5), or A minor (no root) etc don't make a lot of sense - to me.

Comment: @Tim, In practice, chords are often implied rather than explicit in a piece of music.  In particular, in a genre where triadic harmony is the norm, the presence of a root and third when we are harmonically 'expecting' a chord to appear can strongly imply the fifth even if it's omitted.  You can call these implied chords rather than 'real' chords, but it's useful to think of them in terms of these implications due to our shared cultural expectations for how certain genres of music work.

Comment: @Tim, "...problem is naming two note chords..." that's why I made the point about chords/analysis. That "problem" isn't a matter of incomplete chords, it's the missing context. In context, the chords are usually clear in two part harmony. If you complete the triads and have something like `C E A` followed by `C E G` - or vice versa - it's often ambiguous whether it should be considered two distinct chords or some kind of NCT motion (especially for non-tonic harmony.) Adding the third tone to simply say you now have complete triads doesn't necessarily clear up the potential chord ambiguity.

Comment: I tend to think more as a guitarist/piano accompanist when chords are the focus. Thus, I need categoric names, so they can be played accurately. From the theory point of view, the perspective is somewhat different - so it probably depends on what hat one is wearing at the time. There may still be ambiguity, but I'm playing the appropriatee chord.

Comment: I like the statement **chords are conceptual**.   It clears up things for me and also explains why when notes don’t exactly match a chord and I’m told that’s a substitution chord that *is similar* to the chord that is written that it can be played *in place of* the written chord.

Answer (score 8):

All triads are chords. Not all chords are triads. Triads are 3 note chords generally constructed by taking every other note of a scale, such as C,E,G or D,F,A. The notes in a triad do not have to be played in any particular order. For example from low to high it can be C,G,E.

A chord can have as few as 2 or many more than 3 notes in it. There are many different ways of constructing chords. They can be stacks like a triad but with more notes or can be triads with added notes or any combination of 2 or more notes.

A triad can also have more than 3 notes but if it does it uses one or more of the same 3 notes repeated in different octaves. An example from low to high is: C,G,E,G,C.

Comment: Interesting last para! And correct - it's 3 *pitch classes* that constitute the triad, which isn't the same as 3 note names, as far as I can make out. So >1 C, >1E and/or >1G. Thus +1

Answer (score -7):

a chord is kind of a logic, or a universal;  it's an endless series because the chromatic nature of notes is 'regular' it will repeat ad infinum by doubling the frequencies of its parts whatever they are. [i found CmM11b5b9 !!](https://app.soundgrail.com/reverse-chord-finder/)

any unique chord combines only ***enough* intervals** from only **1 chromatic bass note** & the notation used for a chord contains the bass position + implies a unique triad using the fewest possible marks.

`I`.the roman numeral indicates the bass of the chord according to a key signature that may not be immediately clear , but , since it's just a capital , a major chord , and nothing else is indicated lets just create the harmonic space from the bass note of C natural . that 1 mark implies 1 bass note and 2 *up* intervals:
1 interval has 2x full steps, the 3rd degree &
1 interval 1x full + 1x half step; for a fifth degree.

the bass triad is C E G and on the Staff it looks great *•••* .the triad expresses the **chord** **`I`**,   as written

***`C`,**--*`E`,*--`G`*, - , -- , -- , -- , - ***C**--**E,**--**G***,.-,.-- ,-- ,-- ,

a triad *musical-izes* the chords in a piece, so the chord progression survives for generations of future performance and interpretations of "1=C, , no! can 1=E my bassoon is big as a balloon ?" .

projecting a harmonic space through a piece is the gravity of the **triads** the 3 notes ringing out on time so they basically express the drama of the chord progression

the triad multiplies the options so that music is enriched with harmony that is relieving of passing tones & selective against too much flub. , with 3 notes  there is now just enough elements to **juggle** , to create suspense & bring something to life musically ! . the 3 pitches, notes uniquely projecting in triad the chord, assert two more *choices* of 'lowest' sounding notes in place of the tonic bass note & share harmonic space . . further, multiple intervals from each of the 3 notes in the triad enchant the named chord with tonal tricks and illusions - *melody* .

a progression of chords , navigated by the ensemble , *on time*, uncovers the triads by landing on the bass position , , which **may be inverted** !! still, with the same pair of intervals above *and below!* the fundamental bass of the triad , enter harmony

C--,E--,--,**`G`**,.-,.-- ,-- ,-- ,- **`C`**--**`E`**--**G**,.-,.-- ,-- ,-- ,-**C,**--**E,**

[can't really think of a better resource to actually do your question some justice than this article & hope i wasn't too confusing or boring . anyway they use the word "**triad**" here often to refer to a ***single specific** spooky* set of intervals that are a triad; they aren't referring to 'all triads' always ok just keep that in mind o](https://www.fender.com/articles/tech-talk/the-devils-chord-the-eerie-history-of-diabolus-in-musica#:%7E:text=There%20have%20been,in%20the%20details.)